# how to properly display SSRS site within iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, ssrs-2008

I have been working on a project where I need to load a ssrs site within an iframe. The iframe is acutally using the telerik spitter panels but the DOM refers to it as an iframe when rendered. The issue I am coming into is when referencing the SSRS site it loads wihtin the iframe but the view  tiled multiple times over. In reading I have seen mention that the SSRS site also uses iframes which causes an issue when loaded into another iframe. Does anyone know of a solution for this type of scenario or can you point me in the right direction of where to look? In essence I have to wrap an asp.net wrapper around the SSRS site as it is a part of a larger site and users need to be able to navigate to this section of the site using the main navigation. I need to avoid pop-up windows or redirects as the user needs to get the expereince that they are in the same site even though I am loading ssrs from another server. Attached is a screen shot of what the tiling looks like.   The site is small so I am not using masterpages it is loaded directly within an asp.net document. 
[image]
Any tips or suggestions are always appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from experience I've found IFRAMEs and FRAMEs with SSRS 2008 did not work reliably (admittedly I had IE6 issues too).

Eventually I settled on using JavaScript/jQuery to create a DIV at the top of the page that looked like the top nav bar of my home page, using behaviors (IE) or bindings (FF) that can be loaded in using the "ReportingServices" style sheet e.g.

```
/* add in behavior file for IE */
body {
  behavior: url("/Reports/IE-frame.htc"); 
} 
/* Firefox-only XBL */
body { 
  -moz-binding: url("/Reports/FF-frame.xml#initFrame"); 
}
```

Comment: thanks Thomas. I have heard reference to using jquery but this helps clarify how it can be used. thanks again for the tip.