# How to display a link on the Contents page

Tags: reporting-services

I have an asp.net application that has a link to the SSRS Report Manager so that users can run reports. I would like to NOT open a new window and would like the users to be able to navigate easily back to the application.

Comment: I've used behaviors (IE) and bindings (FF) that means I can load javascript files using the "ReportingServices" style sheet. The javascript could create a DIV with a link back to your application. As a start, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796507/how-to-properly-display-ssrs-site-within-iframe/5815070#5815070

Comment: Hmmm ... I think I understand the concept. I can essentially embed JavaScript/jQuery code in a behaviour file that runs from the styleseet. As you say, this code could inject whatever html I wanted into the page. Nice thinking outside the box!

Comment: I was hoping for a "just upload a file with this extension that contains your text and URL formatted like this" kind of answer. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer but I'm not convinced I'm up to the challenge of a) coding it and b) trying to work with the infrastructure group to be able to modify the stylesheets.

Comment: I understand Dennis - I found very little resources on how to do something like you want when I had to so the same (but it was easier when I broke the problem into two problems - how to inject HTML using javascript, and how to link to a javascript file from a stylesheet).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following Javascript/jQuery to the /Pages/Folder.aspx and /Pages/Error.aspx files in your ReportManager folder.

My folder path:

> (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
>   Services\ReportManager)

The code to add:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".msrs-site_title").html("Site Title Here<span><a>Link 1</a><a>Link 2</a></span>"
});

</script>
```